# Callbacks in Composite Application Block

Tags: .net, events, callback, cab

below code says I can not convert from void to bool, thats ok but how can I define a callback for a fired event in CAB ?

```
internal bool IsÖrtlichkeitFocused()
    {
      return this.WorkItem.EventTopics[EventTopicNames.IsOertlichkeitFocusChanged].Fire(this, new EventArgs<bool?>(null), this.WorkItem, PublicationScope.WorkItem);             
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
        [EventSubscription(EventTopicNames.IsOertlichkeitFocusChanged, ThreadOption.WorkItem)]
        public void IsÖrtlichkeitFocusedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//do something
}

Comment: but I want to return a bool value to the IsÖrtlichkeitFocused() method, I do not see how I can do that with your code!